# How to `find` all files and folders with 0** permissions?

Tags: shell, permissions, find, osx

I had a strange situation where I've found a number of files and folders that had 000 permissions set.  This was easily repairable via:

```
sudo find . -perm 000 -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; 
sudo find . -perm 000 -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Unfortunately I suddenly realized the problem was a bit more complicated with some odd permissions such as 044 and some other strange settings.  It turns out that these are strewn about and unpredictable.

Is there a way to search for permissions such as 0** or other such very limiting permission configurations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
find . ! -perm -u=r ! -perm -u=w ! -perm -u=x -ls
```

Or if you prefer the octal notation:

```
find . ! -perm -400 ! -perm -200 ! -perm -100 -ls
```

Unfortunately, no idea, how to take it as one `-perm` option.

That syntax above is standard except for the `-ls` part (common but not POSIX) which you can replace with `-exec ls -disl {} +` on systems where `find` doesn't support `-ls` to get a similar output.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas any arguments for use ! instead of -not ? IMHO it generates only problems in scripts, breaking pipes, needs to escape e.t.c.

Comment: `-not` is not standard, `!` alone is never a problem, it's even the name of a POSIX shell keyword (`!`) and it's commonly used as argument to the `[` / `test` command in addition to `find`.

Answer (score 8):

With [GNU `find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), you can do this by looking for files which don’t match “any bit set for the owner”:

```
find . ! -perm /700
```

The same in e.g. [FreeBSD `find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) is

```
find . ! -perm +700
```

Both of these work in the same way. `-perm /700` or `-perm +700` match if any of the owner permission bits are set; `!` negates that, so `! -perm /700` or `! -perm +700` match if none of the owner permission bits are set. The other bits are ignored.

Comment: Oh so the `/` operator inverts the bit of the first one? Ie, if I were looking for group instead would this be applied to the 2nd bit?  Just curious now at this point to understand the permission functionality better.  Also, just tried on macOS and got the following error when run interactively: `find: -perm: /700: illegal mode string`

Comment: Ah, sorry, `-perm /` is a GNU extension which matches any of the given permission bits.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that would have been great and the answer had it worked for macOS' `find`.

Comment: @ylluminate: To directly and more clearly answer your follow-up question (in the comment above): No, ``/`` doesn’t “invert” anything.  `!` is the “NOT” operator, inverting the following test.   `/` is effectively an “OR” operator; `find . ! -perm /700` is equivalent to `find . ! "(" -perm -400 -o -perm -200 -o -perm -100 ")"` — which is equivalent to `find . ! -perm -400 ! -perm -200 ! -perm -100`, which is directly equivalent to [Alexander’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465081/23408#465090).  As Stephen said, `/` means “any of these bits”.

Comment: @ylluminate, `find . ! -perm +700` works with the `find` on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sfind` or any program using `libfind` or if you use `BSD find`, you may use:

```
find path -perm +0xxx
```

to find files where any of the bits mentioned in the pattern are set, so

```
find . ! -perm +0700
```

should work in your case. BTW: this is also supported by `GNU find`.

Note that this is an extension that is neither mentioned in POSIX nor implemented in a SVr4 based `find`.

Comment: Note that  it was how GNU `find` (from 1991 to 2013, deprecated after 2005) used to do it as well, but they replaced it with `-perm /0700`  [for POSIX compliance](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=14619#comment3).

Comment: Since `smake` supports this feature using `+` and since I am very sure that `smake` is POSIX compliant, as it permits this special enhancement only in case that the `+` is followed by `0`, `u`, `g`, `o` or `a`, I see no reason for this change.

Comment: `find -perm +u` is specified by POSIX (as being the same as `-perm 0`). It's not clear for `-perm +0777`, where `+0777` could be considered as a _non-negative octal number_

Comment: Sorry, this is not in the POSIX standard. The plus sign is only specified after `ugoa` or before `rwx` and similar chars.

Comment: `chmod +u` is specified (gives all the same permission as the user, filtered by umask), so `find -perm +u` is as well. Also note how the `find -perm` spec makes it explicit that one can't use a perm that starts with - as it would conflict with `-perm -mode`, but there's no such thing for +.

Comment: `chmod +u` is not mentioned and the rule is `who op perm`,so I see no permitted use of `op who`.

Comment: See the grammar. (`op permcopy`)

Comment: Interesting, I wrote a conforming perm parser (see `libschily/getperm.c`), but I forgot about this. Anyway, this just creates the need for a deeper look into the perm string.